# Get repository metadata using repository url

Tags: github, github-api

I can search repositories by name, description, topic, etc.

Details - https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-for-repositories#in-this-article

What's the easiest way to get repo metadata like `stargazers_count`, `watchers_count`, etc. from the repository url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every repository will be of the form `https://github.com/:owner/:repo`. You can then use [this API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) to fetch the information you want for each repository, replacing `:owner` and `:repo` in the URL.

For example, for https://github.com/torvalds/linux, you'd fetch https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux and parse the information from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put in GitHub API token and created a little search engine in Python. Then this stuff helps me to get custom results for a keyword that user puts in the console. For example user said: GitHub. Then the console asks how many results you want and he sais 3. And the program shows him 3 results based on keyword that he put in. And then also i created the converstaion where program asked what he wants to analyse (contributors, stars, comments,...) and at the end the program generates the excel file and customises the rows based on the metadata that is requested from user. I used this method and its worked perfect!! :)